# How to use one RDD's result to filter other RDD records?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hivecontext

I want to filter records from target table whose date is greater then min(date) of source table (with common id in both table)

```
val cm_record_rdd=hiveContext.sql("select t1.* from target t1 left outer join source t2 on t1.id=t2.id")

val min_date_rdd=hiveContext.sql("select min(date) as min_date from source");

val src_rdd = hiveContext.sql("select * from source");
```

how can I filter records of cm_record with target.date >= source.min_date?

I tried below steps:

```
src_rdd.filter(cm_record_rdd("start_dt") >= min(src_rdd("date")))
src_rdd.filter(cm_record_rdd("start_dt") >= min_date_rdd("min_date"))
```

Nothing worked

Solution:

```
val min_date=hiveContext.sql("select min(date) as min_date from source").collect.head.get(0)
src_rdd.filter(delta_count("start_dt") >= min_date)
```

Comment: `.collect` the single-row min_date_rdd, extract the date, use in your next query. Unless I'm missing something, this seems fairly obvious?

Comment: Thanks @TheArchetypalPaul ...added solution to the question

Comment: OK. I should have posted it as an answer :)

Comment: Is there any other way then using an action such as "collect"?